# Javascript UTF-8 encoding not working if i send data via Ajax call to a Servlet

Tags: javascript, java

Ajax call

```
  $.ajax({
            url : URL_SERVER + "SucheMitarbeiter",
            type : "GET",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
            data : {
                userid : setzeUserId,
                nachname : nachname,
                vorname : vorname,
                kim : "",
                pnr : ""
            },
            cache : false,
                              [...]
```

This is the request to my Servlet

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/TrackingToolDB/SucheMitarbeiter?userid=BKOUBIK&nachname=sch%C3%B6nleber&vorname=&kim=&pnr=&fk
```

As u can see, Nachname is not encoding to UTF-8.

In my Servlet, called SucheMitarbeiter i trie to decode the request:

```
String encoding = request.getCharacterEncoding();
if (encoding == null) encoding = "UTF-8";

String nachname = request.getParameter("nachname");


nachname = URLDecoder.decode(nachname,encoding);
```

But it dosen't work. I always get

> schÃ¶nleber
>   instead of 
>   schönleber

Answer (score 0):

Setting `contentType` as part of your ajax request merely tells the receiving server what you intend to send, it doesn't do anything to alter your data - you need to pass it through an appropriate encoding function first.

You may find this link useful: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)